# How to add HtmlDecode in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to pull an encoded string. How do I add Server.HtmlDecode to the below expression?

```
<%# DisplayResourceAddedFields(Eval("Body").ToString())%>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether you want to decode before or after passing your data item value to the `DisplayResourceAddedFields()` method.

If before:

```
<%# DisplayResourceAddedFields(Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("Body").ToString()))%>
```

If after:

```
<%# Server.HtmlDecode(DisplayResourceAddedFields(Eval("Body").ToString()))%>
```